# unable to create new site

Tags: multi-sites

I am new to drupal. Trying to understand the possibilities of drupal, I have installed drupal8 and followed some tutorials to create a site with a custom theme, custom modules and custom blocks.
So far so good.

Now I have this first test site working (installation in public_html), I wanted to create a second site, served by the same installation. I want to try and make a drupal8 version of an existing site of my company.

Following more tutorials, I have tried several things, but I am unable to get it working. I did the following:

- my first site's URL is http://localhost, I tried to get the url http://localhost/owtest working
- In public_html I have created a symlink with name owtest
- In sites/ I created a directory owtest, containing a settings.php and an empty directory files/

  - I created a database for the new site. The first site's database name was 'DRUPAL' with user 'DRUPAL', for the new site I created database 'OW' with the same user.
  - in owtest/settings.php, I changed the database name to OW
  - I ran update.php, thereby clearing the cashes.

If I now go to 'localhost/owtest', it looks the same as the 'localhost' site; if I add content to the site, the same content appears to the 'localhost' site. It seems the new site does not use the new database.

Clearly, I am missing a required step. Who can help me in getting this to work?
My sites/owtest/setting.php now contains

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
'database' => 'OW',
'username' => 'drupal',
'password' => 'drupal',
'prefix' => '',
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => '3306',
'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

thanks for helping me, Ruud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. The missing link was the sites/sites.php file.
Although I *did* provide that, it started working after I put the following in it:

```
$sites = array(
   'localhost.owtest' => 'owtest',
   'localhost' => 'default',
);
```

I can now browse to localhost/owtest and have a completely different content collection that is used by the localhost site itself.
Now I am facing a style problem, I keep tring...

Ruud

Comment: Now the new site was accessible, it had no style: the whole content was plain text. This appeared to be a file privilege issue. I checked all the privileges. In my case, the file directory was of the wrong user/group. It was important to clear the cashed to see the effect.